Run Gradle Code Automatically When Android Plugin Detected
tldr: I want some task configuration to run automatically whenever the Android Gradle Plugin is used. How?
I have a very large gradle project with many different build scripts. Some are android, some are java, some are other things entirely.
For all the scripts that build android targets, I need to run some task configuration. A convention of sorts. Is there a way to do this implicitly?
I've written the code and demonstrated that it works in a build script that imports an android plugin, but if I copy that same code into my main build.gradle.kts file, I get failed class resolution, since com.android.gradle is not available.
The code I need to run looks something like:
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).configureEach {
    val ext = project.extensions.findByType(com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension::class)
    if (ext != null) {
        libraries
                .from({ AndroidGradleWrapper.getRuntimeJars(project.plugins.getPlugin(com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin::class.java), ext) })
    }
}

How do I apply that configuration automatically across my project where its needed?
I know I could write a custom convention plugin, but then we'd need to go to all our build scripts and import it. We might miss some or forget to import it in the future. I'd like to just make the script automatic.

Usually Gradle does this by itself, when enabled: Configuration On Demand,
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

And I think for Android, this would be AndroidComponentsExtension (buildSrc).
val androidComponents = project.extensions
        .getByType(AndroidComponentsExtension::class.java)

androidComponents.onVariants { variant ->
    //...
}


But where does my code live? Putting it in my project's buildSrc/build.gradle.kts fails because the package com.android.gradle is not available.`

For plugin code AndroidComponentsExtension might be the most elegant approach, because it does not care if it's JavaCompile or KotlinCompile... You'd just have to loop all modules as projects.

By change just found android/gradle-recipes, which demonstrates the possibilities.

Unfortunately, I think I've miscommunicated the issue; that's my fault. I specifically need to modify KotlinCompile tasks, but only those that are involved in Android builds.
This is due to a bug I uncovered in Jetbrain's android-kotlin plugin[1].
Moreover, AndroidComponentsExtension is not available in the buildSrc directory. Maybe this is a misconfiguration on my end? I will take what you've posted thus far and see what I can do. I think the allProjects might be a good start.
[1]https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-70150
